# Select from mysql JSON field where array starts with subarray

Tags: mysql, json

I'd like to select a row in a mysql table, filtering on the start of an array contained in a json field in the row.

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int, c1 json);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
    (1, '{ "path": ["a", "b", "c"] }'),
    (2, '{ "path": ["a", "b"] }'),
    (3, '{ "path": ["a", "b", "d"] }'),
    (4, '{ "path": ["a"] }'),
    (5, '{ "path": ["e", "a", "b"] }')
    (6, '{ "path": ["a", "e", "b"] }');
```

So with the setup above, I would like to search for paths starting with `["a", "b"]` and get 1, 2, and 3.

4, 5 and 6 would not be returned as they do not start with the path `["a", "b"]`.

`select c1 from test where json_contains(c1, '["a", "b"]', '$.path');` is as close as I've found, but fails as `json_contains` does not try and match the items contiguously or from the start of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select id from test where json_extract(c1,"$.path[0]") ='a' and json_extract(c1,"$.path[1]") ='b';